# People column cannot be filtered by empty value

Tags: filter, people-picker

I have a list in which there is a people column.  I used to be able to filter the list by empty values in the column, but that has abruptly stopped working.  That is, normally, I *should* be able to click on the column header, select the value "(empty)", and return any items in which no value has been entered.

I've created new lists on the same site and been able to filter normally.  I've also saved the list as a template, recreated it, and been able to filter normally.  Additionally, my database team has not been able to find anything wrong.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be the cause, or (better) fix?

Comment: If you delete (or hide) the web part you're using to display your list and recreate it, can you filter by empty?

Comment: Hey, Aron.  I'm sorry for the late response.  No, deleting/recreating/hiding the list view web parts has no effect on the ability to filter by empty.

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to spend some time reading and understanding the XSLT and XPath in your web part. You say that it works when you saved the list as a template, so you might be able to use that as a reference. If you want to post the web part code, I'd take a look at it.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the web part(s).  I have multiple web parts on various pages all over the site that display this list.  They have been up for over a year.  None of them filters empty values correctly.  To test, I dropped a new data view web part onto an empty .aspx page via SharePoint Designer.  Same problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same problem on a document library in SharePoint 2013 on-premise. I actually have two people columns. On one I am able to filter on "Empty" and the other always returns 0 results even though I know there are in fact items with this field empty. Can you tell me, is the column you are having trouble with an indexed column? And how many documents do you have?